# Difference between Convolution and Correlation

Tags: kernel, correlation, convolution

In our lectures at the university, we got following definition for Correlation with a Kernel K with dimension n:

> sum of sum of K(i,j) * I(x+i, y+j), where i,j goes from -n to n.

Convolution is defined as follows:

> sum of sum of K(i,j) * I(x-i, y-j), where i,j goes from -n to n.

However, looking at the animation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29#Convolution):

The way they do the convolution is how correlation is defined.

Whats going on here? Is the definition given at the lectures wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consulted the professor. Turns out the animation in Wikipedia is wrong. Even though thanks to the symmetry the result is the same.

Comment: Great Job @BananaCode. You proved the Wiki animation as wrong. Kindly suggest the wiki community as well.

Answer (score 1):

The definition is absolutely correct.

Important point to note here is, both correlation and convolution are identical only when the filter `I` is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the way the animation is done in wikipeda would be correct for correlation, not convolution? I mean the result is in the end the same, but the way they highlight the values of the kernel should be the other way around.